# Ruby Array of Hashes of Hashes Map

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash, rspec

I have this hash,

```
[{ "player" => { "name" => "Kelvin" , "id" => 1 } , "player" => { "name" => "David",  
   "id" => 2 }]
```

I checked if each `event` contains the keys `[id,name]` with the following line in my Rspec,

```
json_response.map{|player| ["name","id"].all? {|attribute| player["player"].key? 
  (attribute)}}.should_not include(false)
```

which works perfectly. How can I simplify this and make it more efficient?

Comment: What you show is not a hash. It is not even valid Ruby object. I cannot parse "Array of Hashes of Hashes Map" in your title.

Comment: Now, it is a Ruby object, but it is not a hash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about :

```
json_response.each do |event|
  event['player'].should have_key('name')
  event['player'].should have_key('id')
end
```

Much clearer IMHO

Edit : if you need to check a lot of columns :

```
json_response.each do |event|
  ['name', 'id', 'foo', 'bar', 'baz'].each do |column|
    event['player'].should have_key(column)
  end
end
```

Comment: Nice one. But If I need to check like, 10 columns, how can I `DRY` the code then?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/2-0/docs/matchers/include-matcher#hash-usage) you should be able to do this:

```
json_response.each do |event|
  event['player'].should include('name', 'id')
end
```